# Problems starting ejabberd cluster

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am trying to set up a ejabberd cluster with ejabberd-18.09. I saw this thread [Ejabberd Clustering not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211509/ejabberd-clustering-not-working) where the comments say that ejabberd is not installed for clustering.
I am installing ejabberd from source on a linux instance(through ssh), and I get no message asking that whether I want to install ejabberd for clustering or not.

I use these steps:

```
1) wget ejabberd.tgz file
2) tar ejabberd.tgz 
3) cd /ejabberd
4) ./autugen.sh
5) ./configure --enable -mysql
6) make
7) sudo make install
```

When I try to create a cluster i get the same error as given in the above mentioned thread which is

```
Error: {no_ping,ejabberd@node1}
```

I tried the commands

```
net_kernel:verbose(1).
ignored
```

and

```
node().
nonode@nohost
```

So My question is how do I need to install ejabberd so that it is installed for being set up in cluster.

Comment: nonode@nohost means no any name was assigned for this erlang node. Usualy node name is set in vm.args file. Kind of -sname somename or -name somename

Comment: I guess it should be in the ejabberdctl.cfg, kind of `erlang_node` or so

Comment: @OdobenusRosmarus the ERLANG NODE paramater was already set to 'ejabberd@master.example.com'

Answer (score 0):

```
node().
nonode@nohost
```

How can that be? If I run a simple erlang node, then it has no node name:

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3.3.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V9.3.3.3  (abort with ^G)
1> node().
nonode@nohost
2> q().
ok
```

But ejabberd is started with a node name:

```
$ ejaberdctl start

$ ejabberdctl debug
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3.3.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V9.3.3.3  (abort with ^G)
(ejabberd@localhost)1> node().
ejabberd@localhost
(ejabberd@localhost)2> q().
ok
```

In fact, its nodename is mentioned in the ejabberd logs, and also in the command help:

```
$ ejabberdctl  | grep nodename
  --node nodename    ejabberd node name: ejabberd@localhost
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I got confused on the fact (my actual question was) do we need to follow some special steps while installing ejabberd in order to run it in a cluster or a simple installation of ejabberd can be made to join a cluster afterwards. Nevertheless, I got it working as the correct answer was the latter one. Thank you for replying.